# How do I set the size of UITableView as a subview in a Container View with Auto-layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout, uistoryboardsegue

I currently have a UIViewController which contains a menu bar and container UIView.

On main view load the container has an embed segue with a separate main content UIViewController.

When I click a button in the menu bar I have a custom segue set up to load a UITableViewController into the UIView container using the following code

```
-(void) perform {
    BlockDetailViewController *src = (BlockDetailViewController *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    //Clear view of all subviews
    for (UIView *view in src.viewContainer.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //save destination
    src.currentViewController = dst;

    //set placeholderOutlet to destination
    [src.viewContainer addSubview:dst.view];
}
```

This loads the UITableViewController into the UIView fine, however, it seems the UITableViewController size is set as the default window size which means the bottom cells of the UITableViewController are hidden from view. You can see them if you drag up but when you let go the bounce takes them out of the view.

How do I make sure the size of the UITableViewController is the same size as the UIView it is being placed into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a a CGRect (frame) and set it to the views frame:

```
dst.view.frame = CGRectMake( CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame),
                             CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame), 
                             CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 
                             CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);
```

the values should be float values. This is just an example.

Comment: This was almost correct. I have managed to fix it by doing the following; `    dst.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, src.viewContainer.frame.size.width,src.viewContainer.frame.size.height);
` as src.viewContainer is the container which receives the new view.

Comment: Like I wrote, it was just an example to set it to the same size as your parent view. But try to use the CGRect macros, there are some more you can use to get a specific value of a frame and its more readible than accessing the positions of a frame by dot operator

Comment: As this happens within a Segue then self.view.frame won't work as self is the Segue. Just in case others try to use this code.

Comment: In case the code is inside a class which extends `Segue` you could maybe pass the values in a different way. Maybe setting new property on your segue where you can set a CGRect value before segueing to your next UIViewController. You just showed a single part of your code so its not really clear where you come from and where you go to.

Answer (score 0):

When you define dst, you can use CGRect to set its position, width and height.

Comment: Do you have an example of how that would work? Thanks